# Remover valores duplicados de um vetor javascript, sem a função 'filter'?

Tags: javascript

Olá, tudo bem?
estou tentando desenvolver uma função em javascript que recebe um array de inteiros, e remove do array apenas os termos repetidos, sei que existem funções pré determinadas para isso, mas estou testando desenvolver desenvolver de maneira mais "braçal", poderiam me ajudar? estou tendo certa dificuldade.

segue o que testei:

```
  var array_teste = [4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 8, 8, 15];//array de teste para a função
function remove_repetidos(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var teste = arr[i]; 
        console.log(teste);
        for (var j = 1; i < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[j] == teste){
                arr.splice(j, 1);
            };
        };
    };
}
console.log(array_teste);
remove_repetidos(array_teste);
console.log(array_teste);
```

Comment: O segundo `for` tem `i < arr.length` quando devia ser `j < arr.length`

Comment: Podes usar o reduce.

Answer (score 1):

Acabei de ver o erro que você cometeu, você criou um laço infinito, no segundo `for` você comparou `i` ao invés de `j`, substitua:

```
for (var j = 1; i < arr.length; j++) {
```

Por:

```
for (var j = 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
```

---

Minha resposta antiga, caso queira levar em consideração.

Eu usei praticamente a mesma lógica que você

```js
let array_teste = [4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 8, 8, 15]

const remove_repetidos = (arr) => {
  let copiaArr = arr

  arr.forEach((elemento, index) => {
    if (elemento === copiaArr[index]) {
      arr.splice(index, 1)
    }
  })
}

remove_repetidos(array_teste)
console.log(array_teste)
```

A diferença foi que eu usei `forEach`, mas você pode substituir por um `for`, caso queira.

Usando a mesma base de código que você eu faria assim:

```js
let array_teste = [4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 8, 8, 15] // array de teste para a função

function remove_repetidos(arr) {
  let copiaArr = arr

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (arr[i] === copiaArr[j]) {
        arr.splice(j, 1)
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(array_teste);
remove_repetidos(array_teste);
console.log(array_teste);
```